# Adjusting column width in 'Longtable'

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

Apologies if this is a straightforward question, but how do you separate the columns in the following table so that the text isn't so close together?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage,caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
\section*{Abbreviations}
\begin{longtable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{60pt}
\centering
  \small
 % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
        \vspace{-5.5mm}%
\begin{longtable}
\toprule
{Abbreviation}&{Explanation}\\[0.5 ex]
\midrule
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
\bottomrule
 \end{longtable}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \vspace{50mm}

\label{table:ETD Raman}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I have gone through every line of code, changing paameters, but can't seem to move the text. I've attached my MWE and a picture of the output.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Column width]

Comment: Why did you nest a long table in another long table? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: increase `\tabcolsep`?

Comment: Your `begin{longtable} ` also misses the column types. Additionally, you seem to want to use this kind of table for a list of abbreviations. You might therefor be interested in the `glossaries-extra` or `nomencl` packages that can automatize this task.

Comment: Notice that your code did not compile properly. The two columns are glued to each other. If you look at the log you'll see a *lot* of errors. Your LaTeX editor is probably reporting you these errors.

Comment: if you get an error message then do not even look at the pdf, which (as here) will be nonsense. You have not specified any columns so any output is purely accidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example has *many* problems...

- You are using `longtable` but you did not `\usepackage{longtable}`;
- As @Bernard pointed out, you don't have (must not?) to nest two `longtable` wnvironments. I changed the outer environment to `table`;
- The answer to your *actual* question is: remove the `\setlength\tabcolsep{60pt}`. This line increases the width of each column by `120pt`;
- The `longtable`, as any other tabular environment (`tabular`, `tabularx`, etc.), takes a mandatory argument that is the column descriptors. I used tho centered columns for you (`{c c}`);
- And I removed a line break after `\label{table:ETD Raman}`.
- You don't need to use `\centering` for longtable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage,caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
% \usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
\section*{Abbreviations}
% \begin{table}
% \setlength\tabcolsep{60pt}
% \centering
 % your table
\hspace*{-18mm}%
\vspace{-5.5mm}%
{\small
\begin{longtable}{c c}
\toprule
{Abbreviation}&{Explanation}\\[0.5 ex]
\midrule
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
\bottomrule
\label{table:ETD Raman}
 \end{longtable}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \vspace{50mm}
}

% \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `longtable` in `table` environment has not sense. in table is simpler use `tabular` or other table environments which are not designed to span table over many pages.

Comment: Also, a longtable is automatically centred by default.

Comment: @Zarko I didn't know that. To tell you the truth, I have never used `longtable`. But what if I want a caption to the table?

Comment: for example: `\begin{table}\centering\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}\caption{....}\label{fig:...}\end{table}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko Oooohh, now I understood why... The floating environment doesn't let the `longtable` split at the page break. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, much appreciated! It looks like being a competent Tex user will be tough! I have tried several of the solutions suggested so far and they all seem to work. However I notice that my table now fails to split across pages.  In my original MWE, the table splits across two pages nicely (I added a lot of entries in the table for this reason). Is there a way to maintain the way the table is split AND 'un-glue' the columns in the ways suggested by your comments above?

Comment: @Kevin Oops, sorry, my bad. I edited my answer. As Zarko said, you cannot use a `longtable` inside a `table` environment, as the `table` will not allow the longtable to break over pages.

Answer (score 0):

Update: problem solved! Turns out the issue was because I had nested my longtable into a table environment (this was mentioned above but I did not understand at the time).

I commented out the code referring to the table environment and now it works. The result is the table splits across 2 pages, columns are spaced appropriately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage,caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
% \usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
\section*{Abbreviations}
%\begin{table}
% \setlength\tabcolsep{60pt}
% \centering
  %\small
 % your table
    %\hspace*{-18mm}%
        %\vspace{-5.5mm}%
\begin{longtable}{c c}
\toprule
{Abbreviation}&{Explanation}\\[0.5 ex]
\midrule
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
\bottomrule
 \end{longtable}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \vspace{50mm}

\label{table:ETD Raman}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!